# how to generate very small numbers randomly in R

Tags: r, random

I want to generate very small numbers in the range of `1e-9` to `1`.

if possible those numbers should be from all orders.

for example 1e-9, 2e-5, 3.2e-6 , 1.6e-4 .... etc

I tried this

```
set.seed(123)
kk <- runif(20,1e-9,1)

#min(kk)
#0.04205953
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**
@RichardScriven suggested that decreasing the max number, so tried that

```
kk <- runif(20,1e-9,1e-5)
```

kk

```
#[1] 6.479287e-06 3.198886e-06 3.077892e-06 2.198457e-06 3.695519e-06 #9.842208e-06 1.542869e-06 9.113490e-07 1.419927e-06 6.900381e-06 #6.192946e-06 8.914050e-06 6.730318e-06 7.371040e-06
#[15] 5.211836e-06 6.598725e-06 8.218233e-06 7.863029e-06 9.798239e-06 #4.394876e-06
```

Comment: @RichardScriven even so when the max 1e-5, only generating numbers with that order (e-6 range)

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: @nrussell Is it ok now?

Comment: I'm not sure how @RichardScriven's suggestion doesn't solve your problem. Can you address that in particular?

Comment: @nrussell if you try you will see it doesnt work.

Comment: `runif(20, 0, 1) / (rep(10, 10)**(0:9))`? I'm not completely clear on what you mean by "all orders".

Comment: @nrussell all orders mean from all `e` prime orders. your solution is so far good. thanks!

Comment: @nrussell - just `10^(0:9)` will suffice for the denominator

Comment: @nrussell Oh I see. smart solution;)

Comment: @thelatemail right, good call.

Comment: @RichardScriven - I'm not sure this is such a silly question. E.g. `range(runif(100,1,7))/c(1,7)` gives results proportionally quite close to both extremes. `range(runif(100,1e-9,1))/c(1e-9,1)` gets nowhere near the lower extreme.

Comment: @thelatemail - I never said it was a silly question, nor did I downvote.  I think HubertL should post his comment as an answer

Comment: I think this is also good question and never been asked. I checked it.

Comment: I should have added a question mark to ask "Decrease the max?" as it was not clear at the time whether that's what OP wanted.  Now it's clear.  Good question, plus 1

Comment: I'm curious, what is the use-case for the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `log` the ranges, then `exp` them back to actual values:

```
set.seed(13031982)
exp(runif(10, log(1e-9),log(1)))
# [1] 1.758939e-02 1.343684e-06 1.803232e-06 1.564901e-04 5.603956e-07
# [6] 1.042067e-09 6.536568e-08 1.374840e-05 2.210080e-04 6.245864e-03
```

Comment: This is the same as `10^(runif(10, -9,0))` (almost HubertL's comment, his output has a max of 10) but is probably faster to compute.